# Docker - mysql user is not created

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm beginner with Docker and I'm watching tutorial Docker for PHP Developers by Paul Redmond. But when he is creating MySQL database everything is working fine but I have problem and cannot find out where is.

I'm using Laravel and I need to connect to the database. But it seems that MySQL container not create a new user and I don't have any idea why.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache-stretch

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: laravel-www
    container_name: laravel-www
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  mysql:
    container_name: laravel-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_SECRET: secret
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

.env in Laravel:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

After login into mysql container and into mysql I tried to show all users but there is no "homestead" user who should be created when container is initialized.

```
docker-compose exec mysql bash
root@8ad8531fb0e0:/# mysql -u root --host=127.0.0.1 -proot
mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+---------------+
| User          |
+---------------+
| root          |
| mysql.session |
| mysql.sys     |
| root          |
+---------------+
```

I already tried to remove all containers and build it again. I'm not doing anything fancy so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `DB_PASSWORD=secret` but `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in Environment variable of MySQL container.
You should use `MYSQL_PASSWORD` instead of <strike>`MYSQL_SECRET`</strike>.

[Reference](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)